# I need to update my database values using c#. But there is an error message when running. What can be the reason?

Tags: c#

I have four text box values called txtName, txtId, txtAdd, txtTel. I need to update an existing record in my database table. But the code is not working. Can someone help me to identify my errors. Here is my code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database4.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

try
{
    String name = txtName.Text;
    String id = txtId.Text;
    String address = txtAdd.Text;
    String tel = txtTel.Text;
    String SqlQuery = "UPDATE [Table]VALUES (@id,@name,@tel,@address)";
    SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
    con.Open();
    cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error occured while saving" + ex);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Plese help me

Comment: Please provide error message and describe the problem more.

Comment: The error message tells that there is an invalid syntax near values. It was displayed when debugging.

Comment: You're not even using your textbox values.

Comment: Maybe it's because you didn't set the values of your parameters. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Can you guys please suggest me a new code for this.

Comment: Because `UPDATE [Table]VALUES (@id,@name,@tel,@address)` is invalid. You need to tell it *what* to update. For example, `UPDATE [Table] SET Id = @id, Name = @name`, etc.

Comment: Your update syntax is wrong, this is the insert syntax you're using. Can you show your SQL table structure ?

Comment: I dont recognice the update statement as valid. What database enging do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Your `update` Syntax is wrong. Also add the `parameters` to your `command`:

**SQL UPDATE Syntax:**

> UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
>
> WHERE some_column=some_value;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database4.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
try
{
    String name = txtName.Text;
    String id = txtId.Text;
    String address = txtAdd.Text;
    String tel = txtTel.Text;
    String SqlQuery = "UPDATE [Table] SET name = @name, tel = @tel, [address] = @address where [id] = @id";
    SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", tel);
    cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
    con.Open();
    cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error occured while saving" + ex);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your update query is wrong. Please see [some examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).
2. After assigning your `TextBox` values to some strings, **make sure** that you use them after that.
3. You **don't need** to write (in your case) `finally{}` block manually, use `using()` statement instead of that.
4. Put your `SqlCommand` into `using()`.
5. **Use parameterized queries**

Try this:

```
try
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database4.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            // Your update query must look like something like this
            cmnd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [Table] 
                                 SET   Name = @name, 
                                       Tel = @tel, 
                                       Address = @address 
                                 WHERE Id = @id"; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", txtId.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", txtName.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tel", txtTel.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@address", txtAdd.Text));
            cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Handle your exception here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try adding these lines of code to add parameters:

```
cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tel", tel);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@address", address);
```